# Is there any way to model fluids in a threejs? Is it possible to make an animation showing falling/flowing water?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-modelling

I have to model pouring water from one beaker to another. Is it doable or has anyone done it yet in three.js? Please share any insights about dealing with water in animations.

Comment: You can start from [here](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Animate.html), using shaders. It's r60 though, but the principle is the same.

Comment: To be clear, the example given by @prisoner849 is for 2D fluid simulation (there are a wealth of articles on doing this with WebGL). 3D fluid simulation (using marching cubes, "metaballs," or similar) can be very process-intensive and may impact your performance by a lot. Here's a relevant chrome experiment to demonstrate: https://www.chromeexperiments.com/experiment/sph-and-marching-cubes-fluid-simulator

Comment: Yes, @TheJim01 is right, it's for 2D. And a bit off topic, but I couldn't resist to mention about [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsXGzH) example (of black magic ;) ).

Comment: @prisoner849 Impressive fake (not a simulation), but that may be good enough. :)

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I am not looking for simulations. I just need to deal with water when I pour it from one container to another. So I just need to model the optical properties of water inside the container and the water stream formed while pouring. Can this be achieved in three.js?